# Order By in combo box not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

```
    private void InitSCN()
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "select distinct scn from user_scn ORDER BY scn DESC ";
            sqlcon obj = new sqlcon();
            DataTable dt = obj.ExecuteSel(sql, global.str_sqlcon);
           combo_scn.Properties.Items.Clear();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    combo_scn.Properties.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());

                }

            }
            obj.CloseOpen();
        }
        catch (Exception eg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(eg.ToString());
            throw (eg);
        }
    }
```

I already order by desc but the result show the data still in asc. Not really sure on what to change..I'm using combo box. Thank you..

Comment: 1) Is the combobox sorted? (Check the property.) 2) What does the debugger show you when you step through the code and evaluate the row values? Are they being added in the right order?

Comment: Already check the property and i try to change it to false and it worked !! Thank you @KenWhite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the ComboBox.Sorted is set to True. Change it to False instead. Your ORDER BY is working correctly, but the ComboBox is sorting the items as they're added.